# How do I add a class to a Rect in bonsaijs?

Tags: bonsaijs

I need to add a class to a Rect. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
bar = (new Rect(x, ySegment * 10 + 30 + margin, w, 0)
                    .attr('opacity', 0.8)
                    .attr('class', data[i].segments[j].color)
                    .addTo(stage));
```

the class `attr` is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DisplayObject` like `Rect` isn't the representation of an HTMLElement. That's why custom attributes like "class" don't work. If your intention is to re-use attributes for different DisplayObjects, then try the following:

```
var myAttrs = {
  fillColor: 'red',
  opacity: 0.5
};

new Rect(20, 20, 100, 100).attr(myAttrs).addTo(stage);
new Rect(20, 130, 100, 100).attr(myAttrs).addTo(stage);
```

Play with it here: [Orbit](http://orbit.bonsaijs.org/#var%20myAttrs%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20fillColor%3A%20'red'%2C%0A%20%20opacity%3A%200.5%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Anew%20Rect(20%2C%2020%2C%20100%2C%20100).attr(myAttrs).addTo(stage)%3B%0Anew%20Rect(20%2C%20130%2C%20100%2C%20100).attr(myAttrs).addTo(stage)%3B)

Comment: When I manually add a class in the inspector it works as expected. Just want to do the same with code.

Comment: You can't do the same in code. Bonsai supports its own set of styles like `fillColor` and `opacity` because if Bonsai would support CSS styles it wouldn't be renderer agnostic anymore and couldn't switch to another renderer than DOM.